# Add data from textview in an array list

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to add the data of textview into array. ***myLogClass*** is a array list and The codes is as follows:

```
    String txt_datetime = txt_date.getText().toString();; 
    String txt_messageData = txt_message.getText().toString();
    String txt_day = this.dayName;



    List< myLogClass > results = null;
    results = new ArrayList< myLogClass >();

    results.add( new myLogClass( txt_datetime, txt_messageData, txt_day ) );
```

I have setter and getter method in myLogClass and has constructor with 3 variable which is as follows:

```
public diaryLogs(int dateTime, String messagetxt, String dayN){

    setDayCode(dateTime);
    setDateTime(messagetxt);
    setDairyText(dayN);

}//end constructor.
```

> **While i tried to add method it says the constructor is undefined.**

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: and the problem is... ?

Comment: Have edited the question please have a look thanks @blackbelt

Comment: you define `txt_datetime` as `string` but in constructor it is `int` , convert `txt_datetime` to `int` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java

Comment: If the class is myLogClass then the constructor cannot be called diaryLogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to add a `diaryLogs` instance to the result array, the ArrayList should be of `diaryLogs`. Here I made the modification before going to the other issue.

The definition of the `diaryLogs` constructor is `(int dateTime, String messagetxt, String dayN)`, that being said, that function is expecting an int, and then two strings as parameters.

To get this working you need to convert the string `txt_datetime` to int before passing it to the constructor.

```
String txt_datetime = txt_date.getText().toString();; 
String txt_messageData = txt_message.getText().toString();
String txt_day = this.dayName;

// Convert to Integer
int txt_datetime_int = Integer.parseInt(txt_datetime);

// Define the ArrayList as diaryLogs
List< diaryLogs > results = null;
results = new ArrayList< diaryLogs >();

// Pass as Integer
results.add( new diaryLogs( txt_datetime_int , txt_messageData, txt_day )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
results.add( new diaryLogs( txt_datetime, txt_messageData, txt_day ) );
```

`txt_datetime` is a String while Integer is expected. This is why you get this message.